# Пересчет корзины товаров

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно запоминать первоначальное значение количества товара и его суммы до изменения пользователем его кол-ва. Необходимо это для того, чтобы пересчет в корзине работал правильно.

**Первая операция:** (введенное кол-во) - (первоначальное кол-во) = результат.

**Вторая операция:** (итоговое кол-во корзины) + (результат).

Математически считать все должно правильно. С суммой точно также.

Сейчас у меня считает не корректно. Из-за того, что не запоминает значение суммы и кол-ва.

```js
 $(".kolvo").each(function(){   
    var cart_qty_start = parseInt($(this).closest('.js_cart').find('.kolvo').val(),10),
        cart_sum_start = parseInt($('.cart_total_sum').text(),10);
   
    $(this).change(function(){             
        var cart_product = $(this).closest('.js_cart'),
          cart_qty=parseInt(cart_product.find('.kolvo').val(),10), 
            cart_nas = parseInt(cart_product.find('.z_price').text(),10),
         cart_total_quantity = parseInt($('.cart_total_quantity').text(),10),
            cart_total_sum = parseInt($('.cart_total_sum').text(),10),
            vbn = cart_qty - cart_qty_start,
            nbv = cart_total_sum - cart_sum_start;
              
            var totals_cart_quantity = cart_total_quantity+vbn;                                      
            var totals_cart_sum = cart_total_sum+nbv;
                                                                
            $(".cart_total_quantity").text(totals_cart_quantity); 
            $(".cart_total_sum").text(totals_cart_sum);                        
    });
});
```

```css
.table{text-align: center;}
.kolvo{width:40px;text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>        
          <td>Имя</td>
          <td>Кол-во</td> 
          <td>Цена</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="js_cart">        
          <td>Товар №1</td>
          <td><input class="kolvo"  type="number" value="1" /></td> 
          <td class="z_price">450</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="js_cart">        
          <td>Товар №2</td>
          <td><input class="kolvo"  type="number" value="1" /></td> 
          <td class="z_price">550</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Итого:</td>
  <td colspan="2"  align="right">
          <span class="cart_total_quantity">2</span> шт. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="cart_total_sum">1000</span> руб. 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***Обновление:***

```
$(".kolvo").on("change keyup", function(){
  var totals_cart_quantity = 0,
      totals_cart_sum = 0,
      id = $(this).attr("id");    
      id=id.substr(2);

      $(".js_cart").each(function() {
         var cart_qty = parseInt($(this).find(".kolvo").val(),10),   
             cart_price = parseInt($(this).find('.z_price').text(),10);                                          

         $.ajax({
            url: '/'+"cart/qty="+cart_qty+"/id="+id,
            data: {id: id, cart_qty: cart_qty},
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(res){

              totals_cart_quantity = totals_cart_quantity + cart_qty;
              totals_cart_sum = totals_cart_sum + cart_qty * cart_price;

              $(".cart_total_quantity").text(totals_cart_quantity); 
              $(".cart_total_sum").text(totals_cart_sum);

          },
          error: function(){
            alert('Ошибка!');
          }
        });
     });                                                           
});
```

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, цель этого кода, и зачем здесь ajax, если результат запроса никак не используется.

Comment: @Igor Сейчас у меня пересчет количества и суммы товара в корзине работает с перезагрузкой страницы. Я же пытаюсь реализовать это всё без перезагрузки. Если убрать ajax, то считать считает, но как перезагрузишь страницу - все скидывается обратно. А с ajax вроде, как всё работает, перезагружаешь страницу и результат остаётся (но через раз можно сказать). Может что-то я не правильно делаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Igor В `res` попадает весь шаблон сайта. Выводил alert-ом.

Comment: Изменил код в ответе. Надо отделить отправку информации на сервер от перебора записей товаров.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо Вам большое!:) Как возможность появится, сразу проверю. Напишу Вам после проверки.

Comment: @Igor Я добавил всплывающее уведомление и loader при пересчете товара. loader через `beforeSend`. Когда кликаю на поле input (т.е. ставлю курсор), чтобы ввести вручную число кол-ва товара - при новом введенном числе loader показывается и уведомление о успешном обновлении кол-ва товара в корзине показывается отлично, но когда убираешь курсор с поля input тоже выходят уведомления, т.е. посылается запрос два раза на одно и тоже кол-во товара. Я так понимаю это срабатывает `change keyup` после убирания курсора с поля а при вводе нового числа вручную срабатывает `each`. Как-то можно это исправить?

Comment: Изменил код в ответе. Смотрите около комментария `// avoid repeating requests/calculations`.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо!:) Как Вы считаете, правильно ли сейчас работает пересчет? Ставим курсор на поле ввода и начинаем вводить число 22, сначала вводим цифру 2 и уже идет пересчет по кол-ву 2 шт, а затем еще цифру 2 и снова пересчет по числу уже 22. Я посмотрел на других многих сайтах и пришел к выводу, что лучше все же сделать пересчет, когда убираешь клик с поля input. Что скажете? Возможно ли так сделать?

Comment: Конечно, возможно. Уберите `keyup` из `$(".kolvo").on("change keyup", function(){ ...`.

Comment: @Igor Отлично, благодарю! А вот Вы писали по-поводу `data: {id: id, newQuantity: newQuantity}`, как я понял `data` можно убрать вообще?

Comment: Можно, хотя url выглядит несколько странно, обычно данные помещают в QueryString - `"/cart?qty="+newQuantity+"&id="+id`. Я бы, наоборот, оставил `data: ...`, a из url бы данные убрал.

Comment: @Igor Добрый день! Пытаюсь добавить еще изменение в одном столбце теперь уже. То есть у меня имеется столбец - стоимость товара и столбец общей суммы этого товара умноженного на его кол-во. Но записать новое значение не получается в конкретно пересчитанный товар: `$(this).closest(".js_cart").find(".z_price2").text(sum);` Вставляю этот кусок кода строчкой ниже после `$(".cart_total_sum").text(sum);` Если у Вас найдется минуточка времени, помогите, пожалуйста:) Сразу не стал указывать, думал не будет проблем обратиться к элементу внутри `function UpdateTotals()` С остальным всем разобрался:)

Comment: Это надо делать внутри цикла `$().each` - см. измененную функцию `UpdateTotals` в ответе.

Comment: @Igor Отлично, всё работает:) Как хорошо, что есть такие замечательные люди, которые всегда помогут! А вот только не могу понять почему, например, `$(".cart_total_quantity").text(count);` находится в не `$().each`?

Comment: На здоровье :). Потому что это один результат на все товары, а стоимость всех предметов каждого товара - для каждой строчки своя.

Comment: @Igor Теперь все понял, спасибо. А вот то что у меня в консоли выходит по каждому пересчету сразу два GET: `GET http://test.loc/cart/qty=1/id=1` и `GET http://test.loc/cart` и в каждом, если смотреть HTML, то показывает весь шаблон сайта - это нормально? На различных сайтах смотрю, вообще такого нет, а например только ответ короткий показывается - какие данные пришли.

Comment: нет, это не нормально. Но по коду, который я вижу, объяснить это я не могу.

Comment: @Igor Даже не знаю, что делать, если это не нормально. В гугл хроме в консоли кажет success, а вот в мозиле, как указал выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function UpdateTotals() {
  var count = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  var sumThis;

  $(".js_cart").each(function() {
    count = count + parseInt($(this).find(".kolvo").val());
    sumThis = parseInt($(this).find(".kolvo").val()) *
              parseInt($(this).find(".z_price").text());
    sum = sum + sumThis;
    $(this).find(".z_price2").text(sumThis);
  });

  $(".cart_total_quantity").text(count); 
  $(".cart_total_sum").text(sum);                        
}

$(".kolvo").on("change keyup", function(){
  var oldQuantity = parseInt($(this).data("quantity"));  
  var newQuantity = parseInt($(this).val());  

  // avoid repeating requests/calculations
  if (oldQuantity == newQuantity)
    return;

  $(this).data("quantity", newQuantity);

  var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(2);

  // 1. send the changing item info to the server 
  $.ajax({
    url: '/'+"cart/qty="+newQuantity+"/id="+id,
    // why do we need data, if values are already in url?
    data: {id: id, cart_qty: cart_qty},
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res){
      console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(request){
      console.log(request);
    }
  });

  // 2. recalculate the number of things bought and what they cost
  UpdateTotals();
});
```

```css
.table{text-align: center;}
.kolvo{width:40px;text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>        
          <td>Имя</td>
          <td>Кол-во</td> 
          <td>Цена</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="js_cart">        
          <td>Товар №1</td>
          <td><input class="kolvo"  type="number" value="1" /></td> 
          <td class="z_price">450</td> 
          <td class="z_price2">450</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr class="js_cart">        
          <td>Товар №2</td>
          <td><input class="kolvo"  type="number" value="1" /></td> 
          <td class="z_price">550</td> 
          <td class="z_price2">550</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Итого:</td>
  <td colspan="2"  align="right">
          <span class="cart_total_quantity">2</span> шт. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="cart_total_sum">1000</span> руб. 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вот только я пожалел, что не указал код с `$.ajax`. Теперь запутался, не понимаю куда его вставить.

Comment: @Дмитрий "Спокойствие, только спокойствие!" Добавьте код в вопрос или задайте новый вопрос, а ссылку мне сюда напишите, чтобы я увидел.

Comment: Добавил обновление в вопрос. При таком коде, то считает кол-во и сумму, то нет. Через раз, что странно. В консоли запрос GET уходит по всех товарам, а считает по одному.